# How to view the current exception when breaking on exceptions in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When debugging with Chrome's developer tools one can enable breakpoints for [all exceptions](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions) (or only [uncaught ones](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_uncaught)). How does one view the current exception details when an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 3):

In the devtools **Scope Variables** panel you can find `<exception>`, which will contain the exception details. The callstack for the exception is visible in the **Call Stack** panel.
[image: Screenshot of devtools with Scope Variables displaying <exception>]

Comment: I don't know how to access the <exception> object in the console, however.